# How to render all rows of a table in header of every page correctly, if middle row data overflowed then subsequent rows are not rendered at all

Tags: c#, itext7

I am generating a pdf where we have

Header(variable height) every page.

Header is getting generated with IEventHandler. Issue is when the table content of any row is large then subsequent rows are not rendered at all.

Expected [as we see last row is rendered if above rows data are not in large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZE6z.png)

Actual [Last row is rendered because of large data in previous row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfSbz.png)

This is eventhandler code i have tried

`
public class TableHeaderEventHandler : IEventHandler
{
private readonly Table headerTable;
private readonly Document doc;
private readonly float headerHeight;
public TableHeaderEventHandler(Document doc, Table headerTable, PageSize pageSize)
{
this.doc = doc;
this.headerTable = headerTable;
TableRenderer renderer = (TableRenderer)this.headerTable.CreateRendererSubTree();
renderer.SetParent(new DocumentRenderer(doc));

```
     LayoutResult result = renderer.Layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, pageSize)));
     this.headerHeight = result.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetHeight();
     }

     public void HandleEvent(Event currentEvent)
     {
     PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)currentEvent;
     PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
     PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
     PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
     PageSize pageSize = pdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize();
     float coordX = 20f;
     float coordY = pageSize.GetTop() - this.headerHeight;
     float width = pageSize.GetWidth() - doc.GetRightMargin() - doc.GetLeftMargin();
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(coordX, coordY, width, this.headerHeight);

     new Canvas(canvas, rect).Add(this.headerTable).Close();
     }

     public float GetHeaderHeight()
     {
     return this.headerHeight;
     }
 }
```

`